# Is it possible to pass class member value to class method?

Tags: php, php-7

In a PHP class, I have a member counter:

```
private $counter = [];
```

I want to get the length of this array and pass it as the default value of a method argument:

```
public function myMethod($n = $counter)){

}
```

I have tried:

```
public function myMethod($n = count($this->$counter))){
    // not working
}

public function myMethod($n = count($this->counter))){
    // not working
}

public function myMethod($n = array('MyClass', count($counter)))){
    // still not working
}

public function myMethod($n = $this->methodReturningCounterLength()){
    // not working
}
```

Is it even possible what I'm trying to do?

Comment: why pass it as an argument if it is a property of the class amyway it will be available directly within the `myMethod` function?

Comment: @CarlBinalla: it doesn't work, either

Comment: im not sure you can write an expression in the arguments, you can only put a default value or constant, then the expressions are inside the method block

Comment: You can use `$this->$counter` inside body of the function, instead of passing it via argument

Comment: @RamRaider: because the class user can overwrite that value by setting the value of $n: if I put a default value, I directly get the entire array (not a slice: the method returns a sliced array) without having to pollute the method with cranky if/else code

Comment: @RakeshJakhar: that's what I'm trying to avoid  :-)

Comment: You can't pass a private member outside the class.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir: that private member would work exactly when NOT passed by the user

Comment: Exactly but it's scope will only be inside this class.

Comment: @Progrock: counter is a private property of a class and is actually an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that what you are trying to do is impossible, the PHP documentation states for [default argument values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) that:

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function call.

So I think the best approach is:

```
public function myMethod($n = null){
    if ($n === null) {
        $n = count($this->counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my thinking best way to achieve this as follows

```
class A{
  private $counter = [];
  public function foo($length=null){
    $length = empty($length) ? count($this->counter) : $length;
    echo $length;
  }
}
$ob = new A();
$ob->foo();
```

Comment: @Guest `Public` means you can access it out side the class, how can you pass `private` member outside the class ?

Comment: That one is default value, nobody passes it "from outside": when the user doesn't pass a value, the value is directly retrieved from inside the class, what's strange with that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, But you can do this instead:

```
public function myMethod($n = null){

       if(is_null($n)) 
           $n = count($this->counter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable, property or function call as a default parameter value. It has to be a constant value.

So what you need to do is something like this:

```
 public function myMethod($n = null){
        if (is_null($n)) {
            $n = count($this->counter);
        }
        // echo($n);
    }
```

Comment: I'm really surprised